# Sharepoint Rest api: How i can get ServerRelativeUrl by item id

Tags: sharepoint

I like to use the rest API to breakroleinheritance of a folder.
It works fine when you have the FolderServerRelativeUrl.

In my case i have only the itemID of the Folder. How i can get 
FolderServerRelativeUrl by item id. In the data of the Item i couldn't found it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the following options are available:

- via `FileRef` property of [`ListItem` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem): `https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)?$select=FileRef`
- or via `ServerRelativeUrl` property of [`Folder` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_Folder)  that
  is associated with a folder item:
  `https://servername/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)/folder?$select=ServerRelativeUrl`

Comment: Thank you so much. My favorit is the second pattern. I‘m new in SharePoint Rest API and i learn it by our self, so your answer  was very helpfull. Thanks